# How to Convert email from MBOX to EML using Python

Tags: python, email, eml, mbox

Is there a way to convert some MBOX files to individual EML files using Python?

I have a client that downloaded his emails from GMail as MBOX collection. But I need to convert them to individual EML files so I can upload them to his new email client/server - which does not accept MBOX files.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

UPDATE:
I have no code yet. I am wondering if it's even possible to do this via a small app, if not I'll purchase one of those available online. Just thought it would be cool to try it myself first.

Also, from my understanding, an mbox is a collection of emails (.eml files) and a single email would be just an .eml file.

Comment: @Robert I have no code... I was wondering if this is even possible. So Gmail exports as mbox but my server only accepts either pst or eml. So I was wondering if its possible to do this via a small app, if not I'll purchase one of those available online. Just thought it would be cool to try it myself first.

Comment: @Robert that doesnt work because mbox is a collection of emails such as the inbox. eml is only one email. so mbox would be a collection of .eml files - at least this is my understanding.

Comment: Ah, good point, I somehow thought that was mdir format.

Comment: @Robert just updated it.